# How to check if lock is released on <service>.exe while uninstalling in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, service, locking, uninstallation

When trying to uninstall the application, we try to first stop the service and ensure WaitForStatus reports success. Then we delete them with `sc delete` but at times not all of the files are removed from the installed folder. We can remove them manually but after few seconds or so and that too varies pc to another pc. Here, we believe windows is holding/locking on to some of the files (mainly service.exe) and hence failing to delete them and all other associated files.

What we want to achieve is after we have successfully deleted the `<service>.exe`, we want to check (say, on a while loop) if the lock is still on `<service>.exe`, if so sleep for 2 sec and then re-check until its freed and then continue to uninstall files. This may take approximately 30 sec but as it varies from pc to pc we want to be robust instead of waiting randomly.
How do we check if a file (service.exe) is locked? From my research, I dont see a straight solution to it. Everyone suggests to check for `file.Open (FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)`. This seems unnecessary. Is there a straight solution?

Below is my code on how we stop and delete the service.

```
try
{
   service= new ServiceController(serviceName);
   service.Stop();
   service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 60));
   service.Refresh();
   if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
   {
        //runs command with sc delete 'servicename'
        return RunCommand("cmd.exe", "/c sc delete \"" + serviceName + "\"");
   }
}
catch()
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: If your intent is to install a newer version of the service, say for a CI/CD pipeline, then my advice is to `not` uninstall the old service but rather simply `stop it and wait` and install over the top.  In my experience, uninstalling a Windows Service can result in the problems you are experiencing (unknown cause) and because I don't really need to uninstall it, I simply stop the existing service and install over the top bypassing whatever service management/post uninstall mechanism Windows would normally perform

Comment: You might also want to check the service status in the Windows Service MSC app.  If it suddenly says _"disabled"_ (?) its because its been marked for deletion on next Windows boot.  Another reason not to uninstall if your intent is just to re-install for a CI/CD pipeline as mentioned

Comment: Thanks MickyD! We have come a long way using the installer and uninstaller. I don't think we want to go back. And Stop and wait(for how long?) isn't helping us. When we want to upgrade we want to stop/delete service,remove all the old files and then install the new one but as i metntioned even though service is stopped, seems its resources aren't released and thus failing to delete the associated files. It doesn't say disabled but files are locked for sometime.

Comment: Yes I've run into this problem alot with CI/CD...I shall watch this space because I too would like to know how to solve this. The only other suggestion I have is to continue using `ServiceController` for stopping and monitoring the service until stopped and then say use `Process` to monitor when the actual process is present in Windows task list.  This is because Service Control Manager is simply working off whatever status the service has reported and its entirely possible to report stopped even though the service/process is still running.

Comment: For some who may be interested, so we worked around this problem by trying to delete the <service>.exe on a while loop, re-trying until its deleted. We sleep for 1 sec before retrying. We should also put on a limit to the number of retries else we may end up in freezing the uninstall. Hope this helps someone with similar use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some who may be interested, so we worked around this problem by trying to delete the service.exe on a while loop, re-trying until its deleted. We sleep for 1 sec before retrying. We should also put on a limit to the number of retries else we may end up in freezing the uninstall. Hope this helps someone with similar use case